# SQL Server P2P Replication Recovery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two SQL Server databases set up with peer-to-peer transactional replication. Everything works fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to back-up and restore them.

Can I perform a restore while replication is running? What is the best practice here? Ultimately I'd like to use a third-party service for backup/restore operations, but I'd like to know more about how it works in SQL Server.

I've been Googling and MSDNing all day to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.